# Good uses of abstraction

Tags: project-management, abstraction, readability

In almost all projects I do, I can't help but make objects abstract to save on the amount of code I have to write because of inheritance; however, I can't stop the feeling that this is a bad practice in some way.

For example, for a game I am currently working on, it needs dynamic coding. When the player stands or clicks on a tile, some action occurs, but I think it would be silly to create a class for every block in the game, so instead I created an abstract Action class with an abstract `run()` method which the tile will run on trigger.

Am I using abstraction correctly, or would there be consequences such as performance for making too many things too abstract?

I know what abstract classes are for. This question is about keeping it under control in both cases of the program's readability and debugging and also to not slow down the program (if that's possible).
Also this question is aimed at all OOP languages, I just don't know their specific keywords for things such as abstract.

Comment: Your question can be saved; it is possible to narrow the scope down.  If instead you were asking about why you would choose abstraction over writing multiple classes, or why creating a base class to call `run()` is a good idea, then that would be useful.  Adding the part about Google being a big fan of abstraction makes the signal-to-noise ratio pretty low.

Comment: This is not a specific problem and neither it can be answered in a proper way. It is also not clear what exactly is being asked here... is it mainly about your concrete implementation of `Action` class? do you expect people to give a concrete example of a better usage of abstraction than the one you mentioned? ...

Comment: One might also interpret it as "is implementing of an abstract class a wise thing to do?", which is too broad indeed.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple answer about when to use abstraction is when you want to have a default implementation, use abstract class.

So any class extending it will have to implement only the abstract methods and members, and will have some default implementation of the other methods of the abstract class, which you may override if you want.

Comment: I tried to give a very simple answer to the question as OP was a bit confused with C and java!!!